# Do popular CPUs / CPU instruction sets support strided data access?

Tags: performance, cpu, memcpy, stride

Suppose I have two array-of-structures (the structures have the same type, size, field offsets etc.), and I want to copy the first field of all structures in the first array onto the first field of the structures in the second array.

Do modern Intel, AMD, ARM and other CPUs support such operations other than through a sequence of load and store instructions for every corresponding structure pair?

If the answer is 'Yes', then what about the case in which the target structures *do not* have the same type, size and fields (i.e. when the source data stride is different that than target data stride, but both are known)?

Answer (score 3):

There are no special strided load/store instructions, but the hardware prefetch mechanism will detect strided accesses and start automatic prefetching once it detects a pattern (and assuming that there is spare bandwidth).

Comment: Well, if my array is a million elements long I'd still need to loop over a million elements. Out-of-order execution and prefetching may help me some, but only so much.

Comment: AVX-512's support for scatter/gather might allow such to be vectorized, but the load/store port count would still limit throughput. If the AoS could be recast as a structure of arrays without interfering with ordinary operation, then such a copying would be simple; but presumably the OP already knew that.